# I am sending dictionary in json and its have two array and multiple value but i am getting response access denied

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I am sending two array and multiple value throw json but when i send this i am getting success code 200 and its response showing access denied pls any one give me right way to solve it  **

```
-(void)SaveColumnConnection
{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://xxxyyyzzzz.php"]];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:oneRowColumn,@"oneRowCols",memberTid,@"table_title_id",totalRowStr,@"totRow",rowandColumn,@"tempColName",tableOptIdArray ,@"tempOptid",companyId,@"companyid",@"savecolumniphone",@"tag",nil];
NSLog(@"dict %@",dict);
SBJSON *parser =[[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString *jsonString = [parser stringWithObject:dict];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];
    if (statusCode==200) {
        //Request goes in success
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Json for post array ----------%@",str);
    }
    else{
        ///request is get failed
        NSLog(@"Error Description %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
[request release];
  }
```

Comment: rowandColumn and tableOptIdArray is my array....pls give me right way how to send it...and if i am sending on right way pls let me know........it would be a pleasure for me thanks,,,,

Comment: could you also post your php source code?

Comment: how about user name and password?...i dont see both these things while sending the json request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary
                          dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:oneRowColumn,@"oneRowCols",memberTid,@"table_title_id",totalRowStr,@"totRow",rowandColumn,@"tempColName",tableOptIdArray ,@"tempOptid",companyId,@"companyid",@"savecolumniphone",@"tag",nil];
    NSString *jsonRequest = [dict JSONRepresentation];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxyyyzzzz.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to see your php code as well..Anyways please check whether the following example helps you out... Here I am not sending any dictionary values, adjust the code to your requirement :)

```
NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"pwd\"}";
NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxyyyzzzz.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];
```

Comment: i am just sending dynamic data of textfield in form of array,,,,my text field is like excel sheet ,,and i am sending data in form of row and column ...and i am sending to j son its total row value and total column value and array in form of key--column0row0,column0row1....in row and Column ..